# Graciliscenda - Quid significat?

Tags: vocabulary, irregular-words

"Bene mane ante speculum in *graciliscenda* corpus exercitia incumbens susurrulum quendam excogitaverat."

Found in Alexander Lenard's translation of 'Winnie the Pooh.' Probably a compound word, but my vocab is not yet at a level that I am able to interpret this with confidence. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the original English version reads:

> He had made up a little hum that very morning, as he was doing his Stoutness Exercises in front of the glass.

Based on this, *exercitia graciliscenda* means "stoutness exercises".

Let us then study the word itself.
The starting point is the adjective *gracilis*, meaning a number of things like "simple", "slim", and "slender".
From this you can derive a verb *graciliscere*, "to become *gracilis*".
The suffix *-scere* is used to derive verbs for the beginning of some action; see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoative_verb) for more on verbs like this.
The form *graciliscenda* is the neuter plural accusative gerundive.

Interpretation of this word is tricky, at least to me.
The gerundive (as an attribute) is mostly used for transitive verbs, and incohative (inchoative) derivatives tend to be intransitive.
It appears that the word is supposed to mean "slender-making" (making it a synonym of "stoutness-reducing"), but I cannot quite connect the dots in a way I can believe myself.

Comment: In English "stoutness exercises" can mean either "exercises to increase stoutness" or "exercises to reduce stoutness".